# Appending elements of arrays as a line to a file

Tags: python, numpy

I want to append the array as a line to a flie ,

```
import numpy as np

data1 = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
data2 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0])

g = open(f'data.csv', 'w')
for data in [data1,data2]:
  g.write(data)
g.close()
```

I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    g.write(data)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not numpy.ndarray
```

Then I use

```
  g.write(f'{data}\n')
```

The output is

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0]
```

But how can I get rid of the `[]` sign

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
```

**ANSWER UPDATE**

Thanks to the comment, I can first stack the arrays, then save it. Maybe there's still some elegent ways as directly appending them! Unforturnately the question is closed, please write as a comment and I will update here!

```
import numpy as np

data1 = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
data2 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0])

data = np.stack((data1,data2))
np.savetxt('data.csv', data, fmt='%i ', newline='\n')
```

Comment: Regarding your update: I'd pack the arrays in a 2D array (each array in one row) and then use ```np.savetext()```. In this case you have to set ```newline='\n'```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
np.savetxt('data.csv', data, fmt='%i ', newline='')
```

Example for more arrays:

```
data1 = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
data2 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0])
data = np.array([data1, data2])

np.savetxt('data.csv', data, fmt='%i ', newline='\n')
```